# javafx - how to bind the DialogEvent.DIALOG_SHOWN on a Dialog?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

On a Stage I can do the following:

```
    getScene().addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, s -> {});
```

On Dialog, the following DOES NOT WORK:

```
    getDialogPane().getScene().addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, s -> {});
    getDialogPane().getScene().addEventHandler(DialogEvent.DIALOG_SHOWN, s -> {});
```

This works:

```
setOnShown(e ->  {});
```

But I want do use the addEventHandler so other events can be added.

How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow().addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN,
            s -> System.out.println("hello"));
```